# $query returns results but not the ones i want - having count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll start again,

Lets say My data is:

**Table element** (id,name,....)

---

1, name element 1, ....

2, name element 2, ....

3, name element 3, ....

**Table tags** (id,name,id_element, ....)

---

1, happy , 1

2, result, 1

3, very , 1

4, element, 2

5, another, 3

6, element, 1

7, happy, 2

**So if search is '*very, happy,element,result*': Results i would like**

---

1) element with id = 2 because it has all tags

2) element with id = 1 because it has the tag 'element' and the tag 'happy' (only 2 less taggs)

3) .... (only 3 less taggs)

**So if search is '*happy,element*': Results i would like**

---

1) element with id = 1 because it has all tags (and no more)

2) element with id = 2 because it has the tag 'element' and the tag 'happy' (and two more tags)

3) .... and 3 more tags

---

This is an echo to my query:
(it doesn't fit al requirements i wrote, but its first test to find with matched tags)

```
SELECT element.id as id_deseada,tagg.* FROM element,tagg WHERE tagg.id_element = element.id AND tagg.nombre IN ('happy','tagg','result') GROUP BY tagg.id_element ORDER BY element.votos
```

This returns 10 duplicated elements... :S and doen't even have all taggs (and on database there are taggs with 'happy' results)

---

if it helps, thats how i get the elements of a tag (by name and with only one tagg)

```
$query = "SELECT element.id FROM element,tagg WHERE tagg.nombre = '$nombre_tagg' AND tagg.id_element = element.id  AND lan = '$lan' GROUP BY tagg.id_element";
```

---

I hope it's a bit easier to understand now, excuse my english.. :)

------- EDIT ----------

I Got this query working, goted from: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html (second example is my estructure)

```
    SELECT b.*
FROM scBookmarks b, scCategories c
WHERE c.bId = b.bId
AND (c.category IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
GROUP BY b.bId
HAVING COUNT( b.bId )=3
```

imagine bookmark is element and category is tag (for my example)

It works great, it returns all elements with ALL tags, BUT it return aswell the articles with extra tags,

**for that query a possible ressult would be:**

*Element 6 with tags (bookmark, webserbice, semweb, extratag)*

and i want this extra tag (actually any other extra tags), is something to do with HAVING COUNT ?

I know

Thanks a lot for you possible aportation!

Comment: I did get lost but I hope that you escape (`mysql_real_escape_string`) those variables in your query.

Comment: BTW you probably mean "tag", not "tagg".

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question and start again with "Expected output", "Actual output", "Database tables structure" and 5 sample rows from each table? Leave out PHP entirely since that doesn't seem to be the problem. Please keep the query that you are trying to use.

Comment: ok, i did it again. Sorry abaout my engilsh i hope its better now! thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a many-to-many relationship where you want to satisfy multiple conditions at once on the same field.

In order to do this, you need to use MySQL's `HAVING` clause. Since I don't know your database structure, I'll make one for this example.

**object**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| object_id  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| otherfield | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tag**

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tag_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**object_tag**

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| object_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tag_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, to retrieve an object with all its tags, you would do:

```
SELECT object.*,tag.name as tag FROM object 
  LEFT JOIN object_tag ON object_tag.object_id = object.object_id 
  LEFT JOIN tag ON object_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
```

That gives you something like:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------+
| object_id | title     | otherfield | tag  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------+
|         1 | My object | something  | foo  |
|         1 | My object | something  | bar  |
|         1 | My object | something  | baz  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------+
```

Now, since you cannot do a `WHERE tag='foo' AND tag='bar'`, because it's impossible to match, you have to use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT object.* FROM object 
  LEFT JOIN object_tag ON object_tag.object_id = object.object_id 
  LEFT JOIN tag ON object_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id
  WHERE tag.name IN ('foo', 'bar')
  GROUP BY object.object_id
  HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2;
```

Now this will give you:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| object_id | title     | otherfield |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|         1 | My object | something  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

The `HAVING` clause tells MySQL to return only if 2 tags or more (`COUNT(1) >= 2`) matches the result set.

Comment: to si if i understood well, i have two tables: elements and tags. your solutions talks about objet, tag, and object_tag.. does that mean i need an extra table for it?

Comment: it actually looks similar to mine, but you use LEFT join don't know how tu use it much... by the way, for your query i need 3 tables, right?

Comment: @Tony: Yes, you need 3 tables.

Comment: there is no solution with my curent structure? element(id, name) tag(id,id_element, name) ??? if not, what shall i do now to create this database? and when shall i update?

Comment: @Toni: There might be, but it certainly is suboptimal. You can always wait for another answer...

Comment: my friend, i refreshed this question about 15 times. where are you? lol

Comment: what i don't understand.  it's why to have this 3rd table? ith id and id_object? what for?

Comment: This is a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29): An element can have many tags, and a tag can have many elements, that's what it is. In relational databases (e.g.: MySQL), to achieve a many-to-many relationship, at least 3 tables are required.

Comment: yes, i rated him too,  but what about my situation? his solution is for a different estructure;

Comment: @Toni: Then maybe you have the wrong database structure? I don't understand why you are so reluctant at adding a 3rd table. This is how it should be done.

Comment: please have a read first to my EDIT and see if you have some ideas. i'm considering it anyway i'm just trying to fit now to my code.. update database, make a script to update new table with current values, ...

Comment: Hi its been a long time! I finally decide to restructurate my schema as your solution. This is working great, one question. Is there a way to get all the resuts that match at least 1 tag but order by the tag match count? (tried order by having count(1) but wont work)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: You should `ORDER BY COUNT(object_tag.tag_id)`. Also, I edited the answer, there was a missing `GROUP BY` clause in the last query, in case you haven't noticed.